# Where does return statement comes while using FOR loop in JAVA

Tags: java

I was doing some small for loop exercises in Java and have reached dilemma. I have 2 for loops that should be giving same result, but they aren't. Function should take an array and a string from that array called target as parameters and return the index of a target

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
  int a = indexOffFirstOcc(new String[]{"Mick", "Heinrich", "Pipo", "Mambo"}, "Mick");
   System.out.print(a);
}
```

Loop 1 is clearer and works correctly, returning int a that fits the condition

```
 public static int indexOffFirstOcc2 (String[] stringArray, String target){

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (stringArray[i].equals(target)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However, I was trying something like this, Loop 2

```
 public static int indexOffFirstOcc (String[] stringArray, String target){

    int stringLenght=stringArray.length;
    int result=0;
    for (int i=0; i<stringLenght;i++){
        if (stringArray[i].equals(target)){
           result = result + i;
        }
        else {
            result=-1;
        }
    }return result;

}
```

I wanted to extend the loop just for explanatory reasons. I thought that inside of the loop this will happen: if condition is true, int result will be updated and, else statement will be skipped since the first condition is true. Furthermore, the condition will be checked again and if condition is true, result value will be updated as long as the condition is true. However, Second loop always returns -1.

What am I missing and what causes consistent return -1 in the Loop 2?

Comment: Place some prints inside the loop (`System.out.println(...)`) and inspect all values while it executes. Check that against your expectations and you will find the bug in less than 5 minutes (or use your IDEs debugger tool to achieve the same).

Comment: `stringLenght` is misspelled should be `stringLength`

Comment: It is misspelled, but in this case it doesn't meter because its  the same name of an integer.

Comment: Why down vote? was it bad description?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `break` once you find a match. In your first case, you returned after finding a match. If you have an `else` block, then it will be executed after a match is found causing `result` to be (re)set to -1.

Also, you should not be adding `i` to `result`. Your intention is to find the index at which the match occurs.

```
int result = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    if (stringArray[i].equals(target)){
        result = i;
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I guess I can break with the return statement then as well ?

Comment: If you will ever have time, please take a look at this and tell me what is the difference between the loops. Here i am not using breaks but works as it should. Thanks in advance. https://github.com/martinheinr/tests/blob/master/LoopTest

Comment: The link you gave is broken

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the loop, when result has been found. Otherwise you will continue the loop, despite finding the correct result.

You need to remove the else statement also, because otherwise your loop will return only last entry as result, or -1 if it does not match:

```
public static int indexOffFirstOcc (String[] stringArray, String target){

int stringLenght=stringArray.length;
int result = -1; // instead of else statement declare. -1 here, as not found
for (int i=0; i<stringLenght;i++){
    if (stringArray[i].equals(target)){
       result = result + i;
       break;        
     }
}
return result;
}
```

In other words:

- your first method returns first matching results
- second function - returns last entry that matches.